# 2D Image transformations by pixel

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, translation

I am trying to do a translation, euclidian, similarity, affine and projective transformation on an image pixel by pixel. the input for my program is the image name and the transformation matrix.

This is my code

```
function imagetrans(name, m)
Image = imread(name);
[rows, cols] = size(Image);

newImage(1:rows,1:cols) = 1;

for row = 1 : rows
    for col = 1 : cols
        if(Image(row,col) == 0)
            point = [row;col;1];
            answer = m * point;
            answer = int8(answer);
            newx = answer(1,1);
            newy = answer(2,1);

            newImage(newx,newy) = 0;
        end
    end
end

imshow(newImage);

end
```

This is the image [image: press here for image]

Right now I am testing just a translation matrix.

```
matrix = 

     1     0     7
     0     1     2
     0     0     1
```

when I pass the image and matrix through the function my result is just a little black line [image: press here to see pic]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the matlab debugger, I noticed that that you are casting to `int8`, which is too small too represent all indices. So, you should use `int32`/`int64` or `uint32`/`uint64` instead, i.e.

```
answer = uint8(answer);
```

should be

```
answer = uint32(answer);
```

*Please try to use the Matlab debugger before asking the question: why does it not work?*

Comment: Thank you! i will try this and.. i am new to Matlab and i didnt know there was a debugger. thank you for that update